# Couldn't check equality of date in php using

Tags: php

I have fetched value but I can't check two dates are same or not.

Form and database date.

My code:

```
$new_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['datet']));
$res =mysqli_query($con,"SELECT tdate FROM tablev1");
if($res) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        $date =  $row['tdate'];  // use your column name
        $td=strtotime($date);
        echo date("j F Y",$td);
        if($new_date==$td) {
            echo "Table booked";
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code there is no error in strtotime for date format, you don't get result from object($res).
reason of warning is strtotime don't get any parameter.

```
$res =mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tablev1");
if($res) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        $date =  $row['date'];  // use your column name
        $td=strtotime($date);
        echo date("j F Y",$td);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that, `mysqli_query()` will return the resource id not result. For getting results you need to use `mysqli_fetch_*` functions, here i am using [`mysqli_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php):

```
<?php
$res = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tablev1");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
    echo date('j F Y',strtotime($row['yourDate'])); // change your column name
}
?>
```

> From the Manual: [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) — Parse about any English textual
>   datetime description into a Unix timestamp